# SSH remote port forwarding times out

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm trying to forward all requests to a port on a remote server to a port I have opened on my local dev environment at localhost:5000.

I'm using the following command to make this happen, but it keeps failing with a timeout error:

```
ssh -nNT -R 9001:localhost:5000 root@<server ip>

# On another window...

curl https://<server ip>:9001/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <server ip> port 9001: Operation timed out
```

I have established that

- SSH is running on both client and server
- I can login to localhost using `ssh localhost`
- I can login to server using `ssh root@<server ip>`
- If I `curl localhost:9001` from remote server it does not time out. It returns expected response. @RobertRSeattle
- This is the result of `lsof -i :9001` on remote server

> ```
>   COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
>   sshd    1425 root    8u  IPv4 34175281      0t0  TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
>   sshd    1425 root    9u  IPv6 34175282      0t0  TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
> ```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it also time out if you curl localhost:9001 from the remote server?

Comment: @RobertRSeattle Good question! No, it does not. It returns the content of the url I expect.

Comment: So I'd guess the server is blocking that port for incoming requests. What OS is it running? Is it running iptables? ifw?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I figured out that the firewall on the server was blocking the port 9001. I had to run `sudo ufw allow 9001` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the firewall on the server was blocking the port 9001. I had to run

```
sudo ufw allow 9001
```

to make it work.